# Project nested array element to top level using MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `groups` collection with documents of the form

```json
{
    "_id": "g123"
    ...,
    "invites": [
        {
            "senderAccountId": "a456",
            "recipientAccountId": "a789"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to list all the invites received by a user.

I thought of using an aggregation pipeline on the `groups` collection that filters all the groups to return only those to which the user has been invited to.

```js
db.groups.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "invites.recipientAccountID": "<user-id>"
        }
    }
])
```

Lastly I want to project this array of groups to end up with an array of the form

```json
[
    {
         "senderAccountId": "a...",
         "recipientAccountId": "<user-id>",
         "groupId": "g...", // Equal to "_id" field of document.
    },
    ...
]
```

But I'm missing the "project" step in my aggregation pipeline to bring to the top-level the nested `senderAccountId` and `recipientAccountId` fields. I have seen examples online of projections in MongoDB queries and aggregation pipelines but I couldn't find examples for projecting the previously matched element of an array field of a document to the top-level.

I've thought of using [Array Update Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update-array/) to reference the matched element but couldn't get any meaningful progress using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, using a combination of `unwind` and `project` would work as well. `Unwind` will create one object for each and `project` let you choose how you want to structure your result with current variables.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$invites"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "invites.recipientAccountId": "a789"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      recipientAccountId: "$invites.recipientAccountId",
      senderAccountId: "$invites.senderAccountId",
      groupId: "$_id",
      _id: 0 // don't show _id key:value
    }
  }
])
```

You can also use nimrod serok's `$replaceRoot` in place of the `$project` one

```js
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$invites", {group: "$_id"}]}}}
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/njeKQQMwrz6)

nimrod serok's solution might be a bit better because mine unwind it first and then matches it but I believe mine is more readable

Comment: This solution is very inefficient. It is using `$unwind` which is a costly operation over the entire collection. The best practice is to `$match` first and try to avoid `$unwind`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `$replaceRoot`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"invites.recipientAccountId": "a789"}},
  {$set: {
      invites: {$first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$invites",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$this.recipientAccountId", "a789"]}
          }
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: ["$invites", {group: "$_id"}]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uKVvIRSj0he)

Comment: For posterity: after some investigating, I found that this query is actually incomplete. In the case where a group has multiple invites which reference the same "recipientAccountId" the returned number of invites is below the expected result (because of `$first`).